# How to copy .EXE file contents to clipboard?

Tags: c#, binary, clipboard, exe

I wanted to copy byte by byte contents of a .exe file on to clipboard programmatically through C#.

Comment: did you even google it first?

Comment: i really have no clue about what you are saying.

Comment: OK I get what you are trying to do, but why? What's the end goal here? If you are trying to copy an EXE, just use a standard `File.Copy`. Why are you attempting to read the *entire* exe file? Some of which can be huge, and thus you'll hit threading and memory issues fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
// copying to the clipboard
var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes("Path\\to\\exefile.exe");
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent));

// reading from the clipboard
var readBackFileContent = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
File.WriteAllBytes("destination.exe", Convert.FromBase64String(readBackFileContent));
```

I'm converting to base64 since the clipboard doesn't have format suited for binary data AFAIK.